# Unable to display coordinates after polygon drawn in Zelle graphics.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, zelle-graphics

Am able to successfully draw a polygon using Zelle graphics.py in Python, but I was unable to display the coordinates for the points used. How can I get it done using getPoints() only.

Here's my code:

```
import math
import graphics #must be included
from graphics import* # must be included

def main():
    win = graphics.GraphWin("Exercise 2, Polygon", 500, 500)
    #denotes window size

    win.setBackground("black")

    polygon = Polygon(Point(60,80),Point(50,70),Point(70,20),Point(90,50),Point(100,80))
    #Include "Point" in the statement, else it wouldn't work
    polygon.setOutline("yellow")
    polygon.setWidth(5)
    polygon.draw(win)


main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do that with `print(polygon.getPoints())` in your main method, which gives you `[Point(60.0, 80.0), Point(50.0, 70.0), Point(70.0, 20.0), Point(90.0, 50.0), Point(100.0, 80.0)]` as output.

## Example code:

```
import math
import graphics #must be included
from graphics import* # must be included

def main():
    win = graphics.GraphWin("Exercise 2, Polygon", 500, 500)
    #denotes window size

    win.setBackground("black")

    polygon = Polygon(Point(60,80),Point(50,70),Point(70,20),Point(90,50),Point(100,80))
    #Include "Point" in the statement, else it wouldn't work
    polygon.setOutline("yellow")
    polygon.setWidth(5)
    polygon.draw(win)

    print(polygon.getPoints())    

main()
```